# gSOAP JSON code generation

Tags: json, web-services, gsoap

According to the [gSOAP website](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) the tools **wsdl2h** and **soapcpp2** are used to generate the server-side of a webservice starting with a WSDL file. My question is, if it is possible to get auto-generated code that support JSON serialization.

I'm asking because the xml-rpc-json examples shipped with gSOAP use only basic data types. But I need complex types like an array of points Point(x,y)[] as input arguments of a server-side method.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON support in gSOAP supports complex types, which are populated like hash maps. In C++ you simply manipulated these as maps:

```
struct soap *ctx = soap_new1(SOAP_C_UTFSTRING);
value v(ctx);
v["name"] = "john"; // a struct {"name": "john", "age": 24}
v["age"] = 24;
value point(ctx);
point[0]["x"] = 1.1; // an array of points (x,y)
point[0]["y"] = 3.2;
point[1]["x"] = 0.4;
point[1]["y"] = 7.3;
```

See the README.md in the samples in the gSOAP package, which includes extensive JSON examples.